# How to view table of index in database?

Tags: database, indexing

Is it possible for us to view index in database?

I have indexed my table using `CREATE INDEX` command now i would like to see the results of my index.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/show-index.html ? (For mysql)

Comment: What would example output look like? What RDBMS?

Comment: for which database are you working on?

Comment: hi i am working on Oracle db. i expect the output are in form of table or group of records. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For tsql in sql server, below are the query which gives indexes..

```
select * from sys.indexes

select * from sys.index_columns
```

Comment: hi i am working on Oracle db. i expect the output are in form of table or group of records. Is this possible?